# Why loss functions do not return a number?

Tags: keras

I am trying to understand loss functions in Keras, and I saw that the code for a typical loss function looks like:

```
def mean_squared_error(y_true, y_pred):
    return K.mean(K.square(y_pred - y_true), axis=-1)
```

I checked that if `y_true` and `y_pred` are tensors of shape `(a, b, c, d)`, then return value is tensor of shape `(a, b, c)`.

My question is: Shouldn't loss be a numerical value rather than a tensor?

Answer (score 1):

Since the frameworks (Keras, Tensorflow, Theano) use tensors to follow a connection from the inputs to the result of the loss, any result will be a tensor, even if it's a tensor with shape (1,), representing a scalar.

The connection is necessary, among other things, to make it possible to calculate the gradients for the entire model based on the result of the loss function.

**But why mulidimensional loss?**

There may be other reasons, but the main I can see is **sample weighting**, besides using keras loss functions as part of bigger functions.

In case you have an unbalanced dataset, where certain samples are more significant than others, you can train your model with different weights for each sample (using the `sample_weight` parameter in the `fit` method).

Keras will then apply the weights after the loss function, and for that it will need that the first dimension is not collapsed in a single scalar.

Later on, it will take a mean of the results in the loss function and present a scalar in the feedback of the fit method.

In another case, where the other dimensions mean something to you and you want them to have a role in the loss function (or even if you're creating a custom function that is not intended to be a loss), you'd be able to use the backend functions without losing the dimensions:

```
from keras.losses import mean_squared_error

def myCustomLoss(y_true,y_pred):

    mean = mean_squared_error(y_true,y_pred)
    customLoss = doCrazyStuffWithSeparateDimensions(mean)
    return customLoss
```

Answer (score -2):

No. A mean is defined to be the same sort of thing as the elements of the sequence of things it was calculated from